# I Cant Sort Values while Grouping

Tags: python, pandas

Hey i have a data frame which contains many columns, when i try to sort them after i grouped them it says this `Cannot access callable attribute 'sort_values' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method`

the code is here `df.groupby('year').sort_values(by = 'population')`

Comment: It is same like `df = df.sort_values(['year','population'])`, no `groupby` is necessary here

Comment: no its is needed.

Comment: Ok, so please add [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with expected output and explain, why `df = df.sort_values(['year','population'])` cannot be used here, then I can reopen question. Thanks